# How to print string in raw byte Hex form in perl?

Tags: perl, encoding

For example, I have following script

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Encode qw(decode encode);

my $s = "中";

my $octets = encode("UTF-8", $s);
say $octets;
$octets = encode("cp936", $s);
say $octets;
```

it outputs in windows cmd(set in cp936) as below:

```
涓?

中
```

But what I want to output is the raw byte in hex form, for example, like this

```
E4B8AD   # 中 encoded in utf8
D6D0     # 中 encoded in GBK
```

Which function in perl does this raw byte output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sprintf '%v02X', $octets                                    # E4.B8.AD

unpack 'H*', $octets                                        # e4b8ad

uc unpack 'H*', $octets                                     # E4B8AD

join ' ', map sprintf('%02X', $_), unpack 'C*', $octets     # E4 B8 AD

join ' ', map sprintf('%02X', ord($_)), split //, $octets   # E4 B8 AD
```

Comment: Hi, @ikegami. I updated my post. There are some more problems I found. Do you have a time to have a look?

Comment: Re the update, you get weird results because the character in `$octets` (0x4E2D) isn't an octet; it's a Unicode Code Point.

Comment: It's not UTF-16 either. The UTF-16 encoding of `中` would be `"\x4E\x2D"` or `"\x2D\x4E"`, not `"\x{4E2D}"`

Comment: OK, Thanks. So when `use utf8`, $octects actually holds unicode code point. But I found when `print $octects`, what perl sent to CMD is again UTF-8 encoding string, For example, when CMD is set to cp936, `print $octects` gives `涓?`, why? Why doesn't perl sent the raw code point hex byte to CMD?

Comment: `print` to a handle to which you haven't added an :encoding layer expects octets, and will simply output those octets. If you erroneously provide a string that contains non-octects, Perl warns ("wide character") and assumes you meant to encode them using UTF-8.

Comment: I mean, when `use utf8`, it seems that "中" is stored as `4E2D`. Then I think `print "中"` will sent `4E2D` to CMD. If CMD's encoding is set to cp936, then CMD should show `?` because `4E2D` doesn't corresponds to any character in cp936. But `print "中"` actually output `涓?`, and cp936 encoding of `涓` is `E4B8`, so I infer that what print sent to CMD is actually `E4B8AD`, so why  print sent `E4B8AD` instead of `4E2D`?

Comment: Re "*I infer that what print sent to CMD is actually `E4B8AD`*", As I already said, `print "中"` makes no sense without a :encoding layer on STDOUT, so Perl warn and assumes you meant `print encode_utf8("中")`, which is just as good as anything considering you passed garbage to `print`. This outputs three bytes  with values `0xE4`, `0xB8` and `0xAD`

Comment: Re "*Then I think `print "中"` will sent `4E2D`*", You're being extremely unclear. File handles can only transmit bytes, so what kind of byte(s) is `4E2D` suppose to describe??? /// Do you you mean a single byte with value `0x4E2D`? If that value would fit in a byte, that's exactly what Perl would do. But it doesn't, so that's impossible to do, which is why Perl has to do something special. /// Do you mean two bytes with values `0x4E` and `0x2D`? That would get displayed as `N-`, which is no better. At least encoding using UTF-8 as Perl does when receiving garbage usually does the right thing